Probabilities involving 3 continuous random variables do not sum to one
This is a question in a textbook for which I already have the solution. The given solution involves evaluating $\mathbb P(\tilde X > \tilde W + \tilde Y)$. I used an alternative solution using $\mathbb P(\tilde X \le \tilde W + \tilde Y)$ but it is incorrect and I cannot figure out why.

A retired professor comes to the office at a time uniformly distributed between 09:00 and 13:00 to perform a task and leaves when it is completed.
The duration of the task is exponentially distributed with parameter
$\cfrac{1}{5-y}$, where $y$  is the length of the time interval
between 09:00 and his arrival in hours.
A PhD student comes to see the professor at a time uniformly
distributed between 09:00 and 17:00.
If the student doesn't find the professor, he leaves and doesn't
return that day.
The professor will spend the same amount of time on the task,
whether interrupted by the student or not.

What is the probability that the student will find the professor?
Solution:
$\tilde X \triangleq \text{time spent on task}$
$\tilde Y \triangleq \text{arrival time of professor}$
$\tilde W \triangleq \text{arrival time of student in hours}$
Then clearly we seek $\mathbb P(\tilde Y \le \tilde W \le \tilde X+\tilde Y)$.
($\tilde X, \tilde Y, \tilde W$ are all independent.)
$\mathbb P(\tilde Y \le \tilde W \le \tilde X+\tilde Y) = 1-(\mathbb P(\tilde W < \tilde Y)+\mathbb P(\tilde W>\tilde X+\tilde Y))$
$\mathbb P(\tilde W < \tilde Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbb P(\tilde W<\tilde Y|\tilde Y=y) \phi_{\tilde Y}(y) \, dy$
$=\int_0^4 \cfrac{1}{4} \mathbb P(\tilde W<y) \, dy$
$=\int_0^4 \cfrac{1}{4} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi_{\tilde W}(w) \, dw \, dy$
$=\cfrac{1}{32}\int_0^4 \int_0^y dw \, dy = \cfrac{1}{4}$
$\mathbb P(\tilde W > \tilde X+\tilde Y) = \mathbb P(\tilde X < \tilde W-\tilde Y)$
$=\int_0^4 \int_y^8 \mathbb P(\tilde X \le w-y)\phi_{\tilde W, \tilde Y}(w,y) \, dw \, dy$
$=\int_0^4 \int_y^8 \left(1-e^{-\cfrac{w-y}{5-y} }\right)\cfrac{1}{32} \, dw \, dy$
$=\cfrac{1}{32} \int_0^4 \left(w + (5-y)e^{-\cfrac{w-y}{5-y} }\right)\bigg|_y^8 \, dy$
$=\cfrac{1}{32}\int_0^4 \left(8 + (5-y)e^{-\cfrac{8-y}{5-y} } - y - (5-y)\cdot 1\right)\, dy$
$=\cfrac{1}{32} \int_0^4 \left(3 + (5-y)e^{-\cfrac{8-y}{5-y} } \right) \, dy$
$=\cfrac{3}{8}+\cfrac{1}{32}\int_0^4 (5-y)e^{-\cfrac{8-y}{5-y} } \, dy$
$=0.42995$ where numerical integration is used to evaluate last integral.
$\Rightarrow \mathbb P(\tilde Y \le \tilde W \le \tilde X+\tilde Y) = 1-(0.25+0.42995) = 0.32005$

Alternative solution:
Why can we not evaluate $\mathbb P(\tilde Y \le \tilde W \le \tilde X+\tilde Y) = \mathbb P(\tilde W \le \tilde X+\tilde Y)-\mathbb P(\tilde W<\tilde Y)$ instead? Using this approach, we get the following;
$\mathbb P(\tilde W \le \tilde X+\tilde Y) = \mathbb P(\tilde X \ge \tilde W-\tilde Y)$
$=\int_0^4 \int_y^8 \mathbb P(\tilde X \ge w-y)\phi_{\tilde W, \tilde Y}(w,y) \, dw \, dy$
$=\int_0^4 \int_y^8 \int_{w-y}^{\infty} \cfrac{e^{-\cfrac{x}{5-y}} }{5-y}\cfrac{1}{32}\, dx \, dw \, dy$
$=\cfrac{1}{32} \int_0^4 \int_y^8 \left(-e^{-\cfrac{x}{5-y}} \right)\bigg|_{w-y}^{\infty} \, dw \, dy$
$=\cfrac{1}{32} \int_0^4 \int_y^8 e^{-\cfrac{w-y}{5-y} } \, dw \, dy$
$=\cfrac{1}{32} \int_0^4 \left((y-5)e^{-\cfrac{w-y}{5-y} }\right)\bigg|_y^8 \, dy$
$=\cfrac{1}{32} \int_0^4 \left((y-5)e^{-\cfrac{8-y}{5-y} } -(y-5)\cdot 1\right) \, dy$
$=\cfrac{1}{32} \int_0^4 (5-y)\left(1-e^{-\cfrac{8-y}{5-y} }\right) \, dy$
$=0.32005$
But this answer doesn't make sense. We haven't yet subtracted $\mathbb P(\tilde W<\tilde Y)$. In fact, we now have $\mathbb P(\tilde W > \tilde X+\tilde Y) + \mathbb P(\tilde W \le \tilde X+\tilde Y) = 0.75 \ne 1$.
Can someone please point out the error in my logic? Thanks.

Note that $$P(Y \le W \le Y+X) = P(W \le Y+X) - P(W < Y)$$ misses the region $W < Y$, where $W \le Y+X$ always holds since $X \ge 0$. Thus, $$P(W \le Y+X) = 0.25 + 0.32005 = 0.57005$$
The alternative approach excluded $W < Y$, leading to incorrect results.

Thanks for your answer. I see that having the condition $\tilde X \in [0, \infty)$ results in $\tilde W \ge \tilde Y$ and therefore, automatically we've excluded $\mathbb P(\tilde W<\tilde Y)$
My question then becomes - what should my integration limits then have been in the alternative solution in order to get $\mathbb P(\tilde X \ge \tilde W + \tilde Y)$?
